# Facebook comment plugin has stopped working

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments, facebook-social-plugins

My Facebook comment plugin has stopped working. It loads as an empty element (so nothing loads, basically)

Code can be seen directly on this page.
url: http://www.jamesthemusician.com/kudos

It was working this morning and I did not change the code.

It seems to be related to the use of arguments. Currently it is configured to relate the comments to the url http://www.jamesthemusician.com/kudos?ver=prod. If I remove the argument (?ver=prod) it works. I can't do that, though, since I would loose all the comments already associated with the page.

Any ideas?

Also, the moderation tool seems to have disappeared.

EDIT: The problem only occurres if I am logged in in Facebook as the administrator of the application. If I log out, then the comments load correctly.

Comment: Looks like a bug with Facebook. My comments have also stopped working but only when I am logged in as an app admin.

Comment: Seems FB is having problems with it, so it's temporarily disabled.

Comment: @AndroidDev = that's incorrect, this is not a deliberate removal of functionality - it'ss tracking in Facebook's API bug tracker here: 
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/383938611736678

Comment: Update: Facebook has released a fix for this problem. Although the comments now appear when one is logged in as an admin and the moderation tool is back, still there are some issues related to moderating the comments. This is the new bug tracking link: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/547027415367373